# CSS 'checkbox hack' to set body background color

Tags: html, css

**This question is purely hypothetical; I don't intend to use the methods discussed here. The intention is to learn more about CSS selectors.**

Consider an HTML page containing a checkbox. If the checkbox is selected, the background of the **body element** is red. Otherwise it is blue.

Is this possible to achieve using currently usable selectors in CSS?

Here are the constraints:

- No javascript *anywhere*
- No divs overlaying the entire page. It must be the body element's background property.
- No [future](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility) CSS selectors like `:has`. Ideally the method should be demonstrable in a Codepen.

Comment: I am flagging this because it will most likely lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: no, there is no parent selector and you can not use future stuff.

Comment: If you change the structure of the page and do not use body, there are ways to sort of do it with a wrapper class.

Comment: I know there is no parent selector. It wouldn't be the only way to pull it off though. If you had a way to select the root (not the immediate parent node, but to the document for example), or set a CSS variable there, it would achieve the task. A proper 'no' answer should eliminate these possibilities.

Comment: So the answer is NO because of *"It must be the body element's background property."*. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. It satisfies all your conditions, but it does use a pseudo-element so it sort of cheats on the *"It must be the body element's background property"* requirement since the body's background color is set, but the red color comes from the pseudo element:

```css
input:checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```